# Database query broken since updating from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I inherited a website that had a series of database queries that were originally coded using mysql_query. 
Due to updates to zen cart, moving from mysql to mysqli these queries had to be updated. Since changing the queries to mysqli the function has broken.

The original queries were:

```
function insert_FENQUIRY() {
            $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO FENQUIRY
                (ENREGION, ENNAME, ENCOMP, ENADD1, ENADD2, ENADD3, ENCNTY, ENPCODE, ENCNTRY, ENTEL, ENDATE, ENDATELCON, ENCAT, ENCONSRS, ENADVER, ENTYPE, EN_CUSTOMER_ID)
                SELECT
                    (SELECT region FROM postcode2region WHERE ab.entry_postcode REGEXP CONCAT("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*") ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC LIMIT 1) AS ENREGION,
                    c.ENCONNAME AS ENNAME,
                    IF(ab.entry_company <> "", ab.entry_company, CONCAT(c.ENCONNAME, " - online")) AS ENCOMP,
                    ab.entry_street_address AS ENADD1,
                    ab.entry_suburb AS ENADD2,
                    ab.entry_city AS ENADD3,
                    ab.entry_state AS ENCNTY,
                    ab.entry_postcode AS ENPCODE,
                    cc.countries_name AS ENCNTRY,
                    c.ENCONTEL AS ENTEL,
                    CURDATE() AS ENDATE,
                    CURDATE() AS ENDATELCON,
                    "X" AS ENCAT,
                    1 AS ENCONSRS,
                    "WWW" AS ENADVER,
                    "70" AS ENTYPE,
                    c.ENCON_ID AS EN_CUSTOMER_ID
                FROM FENQCON c
                LEFT JOIN address_book ab ON ab.address_book_id = c.ENCON_ZEN_DEFAULT_ADDRESS_ID
                LEFT JOIN countries cc ON cc.countries_id = ab.entry_country_id
                WHERE c.ENCON_ID = %d
                LIMIT 1',
                $_SESSION['customer_id']);
            mysql_query($sql) or error_log("KG insert_FENQUIRY() : ". mysql_error());
            return mysql_insert_id();
        }

        function insert_FENQCON() {
            global $firstname, $lastname, $password, $gender, $newsletter, $email_format, $email_address,
                $telephone, $fax, $company, $postcode;
            $q = mysql_query(sprintf('
                INSERT INTO FENQCON
                SET
                ENCONFNAME = "%s",
                ENCONLNAME = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_PASSWORD = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_GENDER = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_NEWSLETTER = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_EMAIL_FORMAT = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_AUTHORIZATION = "%s",
                ENCONEMAIL = "%s",
                ENCONTEL = "%s",
                ENCONFAX = "%s",
                ENCONDATE = CURDATE(),
                ENCONNAME = "%s",
                ENCON_OPTIN = 1,
                ENCON_ZEN_ISLOGIN = 1
                ',
                mysql_escape_string($firstname),
                mysql_escape_string($lastname),
                zen_encrypt_password($password),
                mysql_escape_string($gender),
                (int) $newsletter,
                mysql_escape_string($email_format),
                (int) CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL_AUTHORIZATION,
                mysql_escape_string($email_address),
                mysql_escape_string($telephone),
                mysql_escape_string($fax),
                mysql_escape_string("$firstname $lastname")
            )) or die(mysql_error());
            return mysql_insert_id();
        }

        function update_FENQCON_with_login() {
            global $firstname, $lastname, $password, $gender, $newsletter, $email_format;

            $q = mysql_query(sprintf('
                UPDATE FENQCON
                    SET
                        ENCONFNAME = "%s",
                        ENCONLNAME = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_PASSWORD = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_GENDER = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_NEWSLETTER = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_EMAIL_FORMAT = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_AUTHORIZATION = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_ISLOGIN = 1,
                        ENCONCUSTOMER_ID = %d
                    WHERE ENCON_ID = %d',
                mysql_escape_string($firstname),
                mysql_escape_string($lastname),
                zen_encrypt_password($password),
                mysql_escape_string($gender),
                (int) $newsletter,
                mysql_escape_string($email_format),
                (int) CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL_AUTHORIZATION,
                $_SESSION['customer_id'],
                $_SESSION['customer_id']    // WHERE
            )) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        // FENQUIRY FLAG
        $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = false;

        // Check if email exists in FENQCON
        $sql = sprintf('
            SELECT
                c.ENCON_ID,
                c.ENCONCODE,
                c.ENCONFNAME,
                c.ENCONLNAME,
                c.ENCONCSUNIQUE,
                q.ENPCODE,
                q.ENCOMP,
                (SOUNDEX(c.ENCONFNAME) = SOUNDEX("%1$s")) * 1
                    +(SOUNDEX(c.ENCONLNAME) = SOUNDEX("%2$s")) * 1
                    +ROUND(levenshtein_ratio(REPLACE(q.ENPCODE, " ", ""), REPLACE("%4$s", " ", "")) / 100 * 2)
                    +ROUND(levenshtein_ratio(q.ENCOMP, "%5$s") / 100 * 2)
                    AS Score
            FROM FENQCON c
            LEFT JOIN FENQUIRY q ON q.ENCSUNIQUE = c.ENCONCSUNIQUE
            WHERE c.ENCONEMAIL = "%3$s"
            ORDER BY Score DESC, c.ENCON_ID ASC
            LIMIT 1',
            mysql_escape_string($firstname),        // %1
            mysql_escape_string($lastname),         // %2
            mysql_escape_string($email_address),    // %3
            mysql_escape_string($postcode),         // %4
            mysql_escape_string($company)           // %5
            );
        $q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 1) {      // We have a matching existing FENQCON row
            $FENQCON = mysql_fetch_object($q);
            mysql_free_result($q);
            error_log("KG FENQCON exists: ". print_r($FENQCON, true));

            $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $FENQCON->ENCON_ID ;

            $FENQUIRY = null;
            if ($FENQCON->ENCONCSUNIQUE > 0) {      // Fetch a linked FENQUIRY row if it exists and is linked!
                $q = mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM FENQUIRY WHERE ENCSUNIQUE = %d', $FENQCON->ENCONCSUNIQUE));
                $FENQUIRY = mysql_fetch_object($q);
                mysql_free_result($q);
            }

            update_FENQCON_with_login();

            if ($FENQUIRY) {
                // Nothing to do                    
            } else {                    
                $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = true;                  
            }
        } else {    // We need to create a new FENQCON and FENQUIRY rows
            error_log("KG No matching FENQCON found.");             
            $_SESSION['customer_id'] = insert_FENQCON();
            error_log("KG New FENQCON added with ENCON_ID: ". $_SESSION['customer_id']);

            $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = true;
        }
```

All was working fine at this point.
Having updated the queries to use mysqli as shown below, it only partly functions now.

```
            function insert_FENQUIRY() {
            $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
            $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO FENQUIRY
                (ENREGION, ENNAME, ENCOMP, ENADD1, ENADD2, ENADD3, ENCNTY, ENPCODE, ENCNTRY, ENTEL, ENDATE, ENDATELCON, ENCAT, ENCONSRS, ENADVER, ENTYPE, EN_CUSTOMER_ID)
                SELECT
                    (SELECT region FROM postcode2region WHERE ab.entry_postcode REGEXP CONCAT("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*") ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC LIMIT 1) AS ENREGION,
                    c.ENCONNAME AS ENNAME,
                    IF(ab.entry_company <> "", ab.entry_company, CONCAT(c.ENCONNAME, " - online")) AS ENCOMP,
                    ab.entry_street_address AS ENADD1,
                    ab.entry_suburb AS ENADD2,
                    ab.entry_city AS ENADD3,
                    ab.entry_state AS ENCNTY,
                    ab.entry_postcode AS ENPCODE,
                    cc.countries_name AS ENCNTRY,
                    c.ENCONTEL AS ENTEL,
                    CURDATE() AS ENDATE,
                    CURDATE() AS ENDATELCON,
                    "X" AS ENCAT,
                    1 AS ENCONSRS,
                    "WWW" AS ENADVER,
                    "70" AS ENTYPE,
                    c.ENCON_ID AS EN_CUSTOMER_ID
                FROM FENQCON c
                LEFT JOIN address_book ab ON ab.address_book_id = c.ENCON_ZEN_DEFAULT_ADDRESS_ID
                LEFT JOIN countries cc ON cc.countries_id = ab.entry_country_id
                WHERE c.ENCON_ID = %d
                LIMIT 1',
                $_SESSION['customer_id']);
            mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or error_log("KG insert_FENQUIRY() : ". mysql_error());
            return mysqli_insert_id($connect);
        }

        function insert_FENQCON() {
            global $firstname, $lastname, $password, $gender, $newsletter, $email_format, $email_address,
                $telephone, $fax, $company, $postcode;
            $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
            $q = mysqli_query($connect,sprintf('
                INSERT INTO FENQCON
                SET
                ENCONFNAME = "%s",
                ENCONLNAME = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_PASSWORD = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_GENDER = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_NEWSLETTER = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_EMAIL_FORMAT = "%s",
                ENCON_ZEN_AUTHORIZATION = "%s",
                ENCONEMAIL = "%s",
                ENCONTEL = "%s",
                ENCONFAX = "%s",
                ENCONDATE = CURDATE(),
                ENCONNAME = "%s",
                ENCON_OPTIN = 1,
                ENCON_ZEN_ISLOGIN = 1
                ',
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$firstname),
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$lastname),
                zen_encrypt_password($password),
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$gender),
                (int) $newsletter,
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$email_format),
                (int) CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL_AUTHORIZATION,
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$email_address),
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$telephone),
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$fax),
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,"$firstname $lastname")
            )) or die(mysqli_error());
            return mysqli_insert_id($connect);
        }

        function update_FENQCON_with_login() {
            global $firstname, $lastname, $password, $gender, $newsletter, $email_format;
            $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
            $q = mysqli_query($connect,sprintf('
                UPDATE FENQCON
                    SET
                        ENCONFNAME = "%s",
                        ENCONLNAME = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_PASSWORD = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_GENDER = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_NEWSLETTER = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_EMAIL_FORMAT = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_AUTHORIZATION = "%s",
                        ENCON_ZEN_ISLOGIN = 1,
                        ENCONCUSTOMER_ID = %d
                    WHERE ENCON_ID = %d',
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$firstname),
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$lastname),
                zen_encrypt_password($password),
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$gender),
                (int) $newsletter,
                mysqli_escape_string($connect,$email_format),
                (int) CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL_AUTHORIZATION,
                $_SESSION['customer_id'],
                $_SESSION['customer_id']    // WHERE
            )) or die(mysqli_error());
        }

        // FENQUIRY FLAG
        $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = false;

        // Check if email exists in FENQCON
        $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        $sql = sprintf('
            SELECT
                c.ENCON_ID,
                c.ENCONCODE,
                c.ENCONFNAME,
                c.ENCONLNAME,
                c.ENCONCSUNIQUE,
                q.ENPCODE,
                q.ENCOMP,
                (SOUNDEX(c.ENCONFNAME) = SOUNDEX("%1$s")) * 1
                    +(SOUNDEX(c.ENCONLNAME) = SOUNDEX("%2$s")) * 1
                    +ROUND(levenshtein_ratio(REPLACE(q.ENPCODE, " ", ""), REPLACE("%4$s", " ", "")) / 100 * 2)
                    +ROUND(levenshtein_ratio(q.ENCOMP, "%5$s") / 100 * 2)
                    AS Score
            FROM FENQCON c
            LEFT JOIN FENQUIRY q ON q.ENCSUNIQUE = c.ENCONCSUNIQUE
            WHERE c.ENCONEMAIL = "%3$s"
            ORDER BY Score DESC, c.ENCON_ID ASC
            LIMIT 1',
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$firstname),      // %1
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$lastname),           // %2
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$email_address),  // %3
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$postcode),           // %4
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$company)         // %5
            );
        $q = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

        if (mysqli_num_rows($q) == 1) {     // We have a matching existing FENQCON row
            $FENQCON = mysqli_fetch_object($q);
            mysqli_free_result($q);
            error_log("KG FENQCON exists: ". print_r($FENQCON, true));

            $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $FENQCON->ENCON_ID ;

            $FENQUIRY = null;
            if ($FENQCON->ENCONCSUNIQUE > 0) {      // Fetch a linked FENQUIRY row if it exists and is linked!
                $q = mysqli_query($connect,sprintf('SELECT * FROM FENQUIRY WHERE ENCSUNIQUE = %d', $FENQCON->ENCONCSUNIQUE));
                $FENQUIRY = mysqli_fetch_object($q);
                mysqli_free_result($q);
            }

            update_FENQCON_with_login();

            if ($FENQUIRY) {
                // Nothing to do                    
            } else {                    
                $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = true;                  
            }
        } else {    // We need to create a new FENQCON and FENQUIRY rows
            error_log("KG No matching FENQCON found.");

            $_SESSION['customer_id'] = insert_FENQCON();
            error_log("KG New FENQCON added with ENCON_ID: ". $_SESSION['customer_id']);

            $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = true;
        }
```

Error logs show

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given
```

This error is occuring at

```
$q = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

of the following code section

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        $sql = sprintf('
            SELECT
                c.ENCON_ID,
                c.ENCONCODE,
                c.ENCONFNAME,
                c.ENCONLNAME,
                c.ENCONCSUNIQUE,
                q.ENPCODE,
                q.ENCOMP,
                (SOUNDEX(c.ENCONFNAME) = SOUNDEX("%1$s")) * 1
                    +(SOUNDEX(c.ENCONLNAME) = SOUNDEX("%2$s")) * 1
                    +ROUND(levenshtein_ratio(REPLACE(q.ENPCODE, " ", ""), REPLACE("%4$s", " ", "")) / 100 * 2)
                    +ROUND(levenshtein_ratio(q.ENCOMP, "%5$s") / 100 * 2)
                    AS Score
            FROM FENQCON c
            LEFT JOIN FENQUIRY q ON q.ENCSUNIQUE = c.ENCONCSUNIQUE
            WHERE c.ENCONEMAIL = "%3$s"
            ORDER BY Score DESC, c.ENCON_ID ASC
            LIMIT 1',
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$firstname),      // %1
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$lastname),           // %2
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$email_address),  // %3
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$postcode),           // %4
            mysqli_escape_string($connect,$company)         // %5
            );
        $q = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Data is correctly being written to FENQCON table, but nothing is being written to the FENQUIRY table. I can see this is due to the failure of the above query which leads to $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = true; never getting run.

Can any mysqli experts point me in the right direction here as I can't see the reason for the code failing. I've read countless posts on here regarding mysql to mysqli conversion and I think I've done it correctly.

Comment: try `mysqli_error($connect)` every where. go for it and tell what happen?

Comment: did you make a mistake with your copy and paste?  the second section where you say it was converted to mysqli is still mysql

Comment: @anantkumarsingh FUNCTION ded.levenshtein_ratio does not exist

Comment: Are you calling this function somewhere else?  I don't see any rows referring to `ded.levenshtein_ratio`;  is the the entire code?

Comment: Note, I see you escaping a lot of variables inside your query variable;  this is a bit odd to me.   Can you either a) escape them before they go into the query, or better, since you are converting to mysqli, redo this as a prepared statement?

Comment: @nomistic Neither do i, and i just did a global search for it in the original file set and didn't find it either. Is it possible it was something directly on the server?

Comment: @nomistic removing all the escaped variables is something i planned to do, but at the moment the priority is to get the function working again :)

Comment: the missing function doesn't make sense to me at all.   it has to be either being called or somewhere in your code (via remote function).  There must be some other code in here that you are not sharing.

Comment: The `ded` appears to be an abbreviated table prefix;  somewhere  it must be being defined

Comment: I'm happy to share the entire file, but there is nothing at all related to levenshtein_ratio in it anywhere. It is essentially a standard zen cart creat account file that has had the portion where the data is saved edited.

Comment: To be honest, if I were you,the first step I'd take is to try the queries directly in the database to see if they are working.  If that's not working, I'd scrap the code and rebuild this from scratch;   mysqli will definitely work but there are too many weird outdated things in the original code.

Comment: @nomistic I just dropped the levenshtein lines from the query and it still fails to write any data to FENQUIRY table, and no errors are logged either.
It runs the code right to the point where it sets $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = true; but no data gets entered so there must be something wrong with the very first query in the code block.

Comment: try rewriting them?  I don't think I'd just remove the rows;  they are calling a function.   I mean reconstruct your queries, and rework the code to do what you need it to do.  I can't really make head or toe of this code

Comment: see the answer below by Monty;  it looks like he's onto something

Comment: @nomistic I only removed them to take them out of the loop as it were. I will get the function installed on the server so that it's available, but even without that, nothing at all, not even one field is getting populated in FENQUIRY

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$q = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

UPDATED:

Now that you've solved the above problem, it seems you need to solve the new problem of adding the Levenshtein library to your installation of MySQL so you can run the `levenshtein_ratio()` function. This may help: https://samjlevy.com/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/

Comment: That gave me some bizarre error message of
FUNCTION ded.levenshtein_ratio does not exist

Comment: I see that it is a function for looking at similarity between results. Is it feasible that this doesn't work on a mysqli query??

Comment: @StevePrice What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: upgrade that ASAP.  security holes

Comment: Your installation of MySQL probably doesn't have the levenshtein library installed in order to run that function. This may shed some light on that for you: https://samjlevy.com/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/